# Как сделать чтобы страница менялась при обновлений данных на сервере без перезагрузки? (Java Servlet)

Tags: java, sql, веб-программирование, vue.js, servlet

Как добиться результата как в vue.js($store) с автоматическим обновлением информаций на странице в случае обновления данных в базе данных.

Comment: Прикрутить вебсокеты

Comment: Толкать сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuex - это реактивное хранилище, которое позволяет отслеживать изменения данных в нём. Однако он не связан с сервером, как допустим веб-сокеты. Вместо этого он выступает посредником между клиентским кодом и сервером: каждый раз выполняя запрос и получая ответ, Vuex меняет состояние и об этом узнаёт весь связанный код.

Что лучше в твоём случае мне не ясно. Но в зависимости от ситуации можно использовать:

- Веб-сокеты
- API-запросы

Первый случай подходит тогда, когда данные на сервере могли измениться независимо от действий клиента, но при этом связанный с ними клиент должен быть оповещён об изменениях.

Второй случай хорошо подходит тогда, когда данные меняются зависимо от клиента. Но так как ты не хочешь перезагружать страницу, то пусть сервер возвращает не страницу, а лишь данные. Дальше при получении обнови поля текущей страницы и вуаля!